# How can I send a viewmodel to controller through Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

The user is able to write text and upload a file.
Using Javascript, I create an object with the file and text as properties, then send it to the controller using Ajax.

Using debugging, it seems that the problem is in the Ajax part. Everything before that(file upload, object creation) seems to be fine.

Here is the Javascript/JQuery:

```
function AddPost() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file').files;
    var textInput = document.getElementById('addPostText').value;

    if (fileInput != null || textInput != null) {
   
        file = null;
        if (fileInput.length > 0) {
            file = fileInput[length-1];
        }
        var AddPostViewModel =
        {
            "Text": textInput,
            "File": file
        }; 
       
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "@Url.Action('AddPost')",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(AddPostViewModel),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void AddPost(AddPostViewModel viewModel)
        {
           
        }
```

And here is the object:

```
public class AddPostViewModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<textarea id="addPostText"></textarea>
                           
<div class="upload-button">
 <div class="label">Add image</div>
  <input id="file"  type="file" size="1" />
  </div>
```

Comment: I've changed the code as advised by the answerers. But in debugging the code I get the following output: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () [https://localhost:44365/@Url.Action('AddPost')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send the File inside a json. Also, you've a bug in line `file = fileInput[length-1];` (length is wrong, should be `0` or `fileInput.length-1`.

Here is a working function. *This function should be inside a Razor Page* because it needs to build the form action url `@Url.Action("AddPost")`.

```
function AddPost() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file').files;
    var textInput = document.getElementById('addPostText').value;
    if (fileInput != null || textInput != null) {
        var file = null;
        if (fileInput.length > 0) {
            file = fileInput[0];
        }

        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("Text", textInput);
        form.append("File", file);

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("AddPost")',
                type: "POST",
                data: form,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Here is a full demo using the tag helpers `asp-action`, `asp-for` and a small JS/jQuery code to intercept the form submission and use Ajax.

1: Controller.

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult AddPost()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void AddPost(AddPostViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //process the viewModel here
    }
}
```

2: View

```
@model AddPostViewModel

<form asp-action="AddPost" id="theForm">
    <textarea asp-for="Text"></textarea>
    <input asp-for="File" size="1" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#theForm").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: $(this).prop("action"),
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function() {
                        console.log("form sent!");
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hi. I replaced my code with yours, but it did not work. The model did not reach the AddPost action in the controller.

Comment: @NatashaDrost maybe you're having troubles with `AntiforgeryToken`. Try adding the `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` to `AddPost` action. I will update my answer will a full demostration.

Comment: In debugging the code I get the following output: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () [localhost:44365/@Url.Action('AddPost')]"

Comment: Then the issue is because this function is outside a razor page, for that reason `@Url.Action('AddPost')` was not processed. Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

You cant stringify a file data and you cant send file as JSON. You should use FormData to send file with ajax request.

Try to send request as follow

```
function AddPost() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file').files;
    var textInput = document.getElementById('addPostText').value;

    if (fileInput != null || textInput != null) {
   
        file = null;
        if (fileInput.length > 0) {
            file = fileInput[length-1];
        }
        var AddPostViewModel =
        {
            "Text": textInput,
            "File": file
        }; 
        
        var formData = new FormData();
        
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(AddPostViewModel).forEach(function ( attr, index ) {
            var value = AddPostViewModel[attr];
            formData.append(attr, value)
        });
       
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "@Url.Action('AddPost')",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. It doesn't seem to work. The model never reaches the method in the controller.